# All of my video is going fast, and has no sound

Tags: sound, video

Movie Player, Blender, Youtube and Vimeo on chorme.
Everything I try to play on my system has this issue.

The videos play very fast, and have no sound at all.
I just did an update, can I undo it?
Should I?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and I just did the regular update when prompted.

**Added**: Grooveshark doesn't play, so it seems I have no sound at all.

Comment: Also, VLC has the same problem with DVDs.

Comment: What version are you running and how did you update?

Comment: 13.04 raring,
I just did the normal update when it popped up.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that I installed Ardour at about the same time, and I know Ardour interrupts audio *while it's running* but I've restarted my system several times since then.

Answer (score 1):

It was just that the sound settings were set to S/PDIF instead of Speakers for some reason.

Why that would effect video playback, I have no idea.

Comment: So, SOLVED, but I don't know to mark it.

Comment: If you are the OP then you obviously have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  When you have done this, you will be able to accept your answer by clicking the tick-button next to this answer.  Thanks.